# Normalizing Boolean values in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, bestpractice, lwc-oss

Looking at LWC e-bikes sample gallery, I found these comments in code regaring normalizing values. Can someone refer to what they have meant or how to do this normalization using best practices?

```js
export default class ProductTileList extends LightningElement {
    /**
     * Whether to display the search bar.
     * TODO - normalize value because it may come as a boolean, string or otherwise.
     */
    @api searchBarIsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What they mean is javascript is loosely typed language and so for any given property you can assign any type of object like ***boolean, string or any other object*** and so it is better to have checks for the **type** of properties passed from parent components using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) whenever necessary. Also note:

1. You should always initialize the variables or else they will be `undefined`.
2. Template **if:true** need not necessarily have boolean to render the content, it will render the content even if you assign a string value to the reactive property.

Note that you will find below function for normalising in ***[moment.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/staticresources/moment.js)*** in lwc recipes repository:

```
    function normalizeUnits(units) {
        return typeof units === 'string' ? aliases[units] || aliases[units.toLowerCase()] : undefined;
    }
```

I also created [this playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1aCg8rAaK/3/edit) for better understanding.

Additional info:

```
    console.log(typeof true); // boolean
    console.log(typeof 'text'); // string
    console.log(typeof 0); // number
    console.log(typeof {}); // object
    console.log(typeof []);  // object
    console.log(typeof null);  // object
    console.log(typeof undefined);  // undefined
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you.